# Delete rows in a table if an identifier doesn't exist in another table

Tags: mysql

First, I apologize if I'm not asking this properly.

I have two mysql tables. I need help making a mysql query that will delete all rows in a table (**table_applied**) where identifiers don't exist in another (**table_approved**) (identifiers are unique Emails).

For example:

**table_approved**

```
Name      Email           Entry
Thelma    abc@null.com    123   
Vincent   lmn@null.com    456
Thelma    abc@null.com    789
```

**table_applied**

```
Name             Email
Thelma AB        abc@null.com
Louise Ross      ijk@null.com
Vincent Vega     lmn@null.com
Mia Wallace      opq@null.com
```

**table_applied** after running the query

```
Name             Email
Thelma AB        abc@null.com
Vincent Vega     lmn@null.com
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM table_applied
WHERE "Email" NOT IN (SELECT "Email" FROM table_approved)
```

See MySQL manual on [subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) and [comparison operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) (like `NOT IN`).